# what rules does designer.cs generation use

Tags: c#, asp.net

Folks,

what are the rules governing the generation of declarations in the designer.cs file in an asp.net project?

for example, I have
 - myfile.resx,
 - myfile.aspx,
 - myfile.aspx.cs.

these generate
 - myfile.aspx.designer.cs

which defines things like *protected global::system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal blahblah;* for my resources.

but until I reference something in myfile.aspx, it wont show up in the generated designer.cs, *even* if I'm refering to it in my myfile.cs (the codebehind class).

how can I force this, without taking ownership of that designer.cs file?

context: I have a someresource.text in my aspx, which i am constructing out of a bunch of other resources, which is why they dont show up explicitly in the aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only declarations within a designer file are for the server side controls explicitly declared on the aspx during design time.  AFAIK, absolutely nothing else will be added to the designer file.

Remember, the designer file is only a partial class that specifically declares controls for use in your code-behind (which is also a partial class).  It is only there to aid wiring up all your controls.

Comment: only during design time? can I go back to the aspx later, edit something, and force a recreation of the designer.cs with the new resources? or is there something else I can/should do?

Comment: Any time you edit your aspx file Visual Studio will re-create the designer file.  It sound like you're essentially trying to dynamically add controls to your web page using a combination of resx and aspx files, am I correct?  If not perhaps you could post a sample of your aspx code so I can see what you're doing.  Calls to resx files aren't fully evaluated until run-time so changes to resx files would not cause a change to the designer file.